# How to compress and previewing .tiff image in browser if the image size is more than 150MB

Tags: javascript, compression, tiff

We have a requirement for previewing tiff images in the web browser, whereas image size could be more than 150MB.
I am able to preview tiff image file in the web browser by using tiff.js using 
example provided in [this link](https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master)

but not sure about how to compress the image size before previewing to a smaller size so that it will be easier to view in browser?

Comment: IS there a specific reason it -has- to be a TIFF for previewing?

Comment: Yes, This is the client requirement,

Comment: Who has to be able to look at the TIFF's? Because the big problem is [browser support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support). TIFF has too much different information to process. Compressing image files would be a thing for the software that exports it. Can I have some more information on the actual goal of the page?

Comment: What exactly is the requirement? That you be able to load image data from a TIFF, and display it somehow in a browser? Does it also require that you use the TIFF file format throughout your implementation? | Where do those images come from? Are they on the server that generates the webpage meant to preview the image?

Comment: The requirement is I have an image gallery component. When the user uploads an image from the backend (we used Sitecore) the image should display on the browser. Images would be either png, jpeg or tiff format. So whenever the user uploads the large size image(currently I saw what its 150MB), it could be more or less .Once image uploaded by the user it should display properly in the browser. I am able to display tiff image file size max of 5 MB . But the question is how to display image size is more than 150MB and How we compressed the images and display in the browser?

Comment: It seems like the best option would be to a) keep the uploaded TIFF files as-is on the server, and b) convert the TIFF files (and perhaps reducing their dimension) to PNG or JPEG for preview. This will make previews faster to load, and easier to implement, but still keep the original TIFF data the user uploaded, should anyone need it.